# Call Python non-member function referenced by class variable

Tags: python

In my class I'd like to call a non-member function whose reference is stored in a member variable. My issue is that it tries to pass `self` to the function as the first argument. How can I avoid this?

```
class MyClass:
    my_useful_static_function = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x11021, True)

    def __init__(self):
        # this gets called with the first argument as self :(
        result = self.my_useful_static_function()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

```
class MyClass:
    my_useful_static_function = staticmethod(crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x11021, True))

    def __init__(self):
        result = self.my_useful_static_function()
```

Comment: Tested, works :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) like so:

```
class Foo: 
    @staticmethod 
    def my_method(): 
        print("This is a static method") 

    def my_other_method(self): 
        print("This is not static")

# This works
Foo.my_method()

# This won't work
Foo.my_other_method()

# This works though
foo_instance = Foo()
foo_instance.my_other_method()
```

Comment: In this instance I'm not creating the def, so I don't think `@staticmethod` works, but the function format does.

Comment: Right, I missed that part.

Comment: @Rick: `@staticmethod` is just syntactic sugar for `decoratedname = staticmethod(decoratedname)`.